# Extended sound control for Gnome

Tags: gnome, sound

In Windows there is a sound control feature: it is possible to adjust sound level of all programms. Is there anything similar for Ubuntu/Gnome/KDE?

Answer (score 0):

In a default Ubuntu installation we can control sound via the Indicator Sound menu in the top panel:

[image]

From there we can directly control the master volume of playback and we can mute all sound.

In the last menu entry we will find the *Sound Settings...* entry. This will open the sound settings application to further control audio settings:

[image]

Please find the tab *Applications* to see all applications currently playing sound. In the example above these are *Guayadeque, 2 Chromium tabs,* and *Rhythmbox*. Volume and mute state can be controlled for each of them separately.

For more options of audio control we may also install and run [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install banshee].

Comment: I suppose all these features are in Unity, but not in Gnome. I solved the problem by installing extensions from extentions.gnome.org. Now it is working properly.